# Traits - property conflict with parent class

Tags: php, symfony, inheritance, conflict, traits

I have this class `Zgh\FEBundle\Entity\User` which extends `FOS\UserBundle\Model\User`.

```
use FOS\UserBundle\Model\User as BaseUser;

class User extends BaseUser implements ParticipantInterface
{
    use BasicInfo;
    // ..
}
```

And `BaseUser` class:

```
abstract class User implements UserInterface, GroupableInterface
{
    protected $id;
    // ..
}
```

And `BaseInfo` trait:

```
trait BasicInfo
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="NONE")
     */
    protected $id;

    // ..
}
```

But when I run my code i get this error:

> Strict standards: FOS\UserBundle\Model\User and
>   Zgh\FEBundle\Model\Partial\BasicInfo define the same property ($id) in
>   the composition of Zgh\FEBundle\Entity\User. This might be
>   incompatible,  consider using accessor methods in traits instead.

I'm using Symfony framework.

Is there anyway to resolve this conflict between the trait and the parent class object about this property ?

Comment: And the question is....

Answer (score 3):

No, it's not yet possible to rewrite a mapped property by using a Trait.

Also, a possible alternative is to use multiple abstract entity classes, and extend your child entities depending on your need.

i.e.

```
<?php

use FOS\UserBundle\Model\User as BaseUser;

abstract class AbstractStrategyNoneEntity extends BaseUser
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="NONE")
     */
    protected $id;
}

abstract class AbstractStrategyAutoEntity extends BaseUser
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     *
     */
    protected $id;
}
```

And extend one of them in your child entities.

```
/**
* @ORM\Entity
*/
class Child extends AbstractStrategyNoneEntity 
{
    // Inherited mapping
}
```

Hopes this answers your question.